# Which library for Document object in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work with MS word files but when i write the code as below:

```
Document document = new Document("Sample.doc");
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: The type or namespace name 'Document' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Tell me which library should be included for this data object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` as reference in your application and, in your class, write

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```